# Session Storage Array Key

Tags: javascript, sessionstorage

```
var items = [];

sessionStorage.setItem(items, JSON.stringify({
     name: itemName.val(),
     model: model.val(),
      qty: qty.val()
}));

console.log(JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('item')));
```

I need to have an array key in sessionStorage. If it can't be doable how can I add more values.

[image]

Comment: do you mean to store items array in session storage & items array will have this keys?

Comment: _"I need to have an array key in sessionStorage"_ ? What ?

Comment: Yes, I need the key to be stored in array. That one overwrites the item everytime I add.

Answer (score 2):

Since you can only have a key as a string, I suggest one of the following options:

**Option A**

```
var items = [];
items.push({
   name: itemName.val(),
     model: model.val(),
      qty: qty.val();
})

sessionStorage.setItem('items',JSON.stringify(items));
```

and then to get an item:

`JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('items')[theIndexYouWant]`

**Option B**

for each item set a different key by index:

```
items.forEach(function(el, index) {
   sessionStorage.setItem('item' + index, JSON.stringify(el))
}
```

and then to get an item:

`JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('item10'))`

Answer (score 0):

You need to first push the keys and values to the items array. Then stringify it and store in Session storage.

```
var items = [];
items.push({
   name: itemName.val(),
     model: model.val(),
      qty: qty.val();
})

sessionStorage.setItem(items,JSON.stringify(items));
console.log(JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('item')));
```

Comment: I updated it with image, I need to have and array key so that it doesn't overwrite the content.